# How can I draw a "shining figure" using R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have seen a "shining figure" in a academic paper. I want to draw a similar plot using R. I mean, how can I get the similar color schemes to make my tsne plot beautiful?
[image]

I have tried like this, it seems slightly different

```
 # library
library(ggplot2) 
library(viridis)
# data
sample_data <- data.frame(x_values = 1:200 + rnorm(200,sd=20), y_values = 1:200 + rnorm(200,sd=27)) 

#plot
ggplot(sample_data, aes(x_values, y_values)) +
  stat_density2d(geom="tile", aes(fill = ..density..), contour = FALSE) + 
  scale_fill_viridis(option="magma")+
  geom_point(colour = "white", size = 0.5)
```

output like this

Comment: Isn't this a histochemical image? Could you also include what you have tried?

Comment: Looks like the examples in `?smoothScatter` with a black background.

Comment: The colour scale might be something similar to the "magma" one from `viridis`, which is included in ggplot

Comment: @CalumYou Maybe a density plot geom_density2d() + geom_point() in two or three layers with the appropriate color palette and alpha values for each layer.